# Binary tree search in Cuda C - Parallel

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

Is it possible to implement a parallel binary tree search? I'm going to use CUDA C for my implementation but any parallelelizing method a binary search tree would be helpfull.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to implement a parallel binary tree search?

Any one search of a binary tree is inherently serial.  It is essentially a pathfinding operation, in which one must discover each node in the path before one can determine its successor.

You could perform multiple searches of the same tree in parallel, but you cannot parallelize the individual searches.

Comment: Except of course the comparisons with each node are so complicated that they can be parallelized, e.g. if the indices are 1MB in size ... and other solutions like hashing them are no option